# Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, provisioning-profile

Since the release of Xcode 8, I haven't been able to complete a successful build for my iOS app using Cordova.  I'm now using Cordova 7.0.1 and Xcode 8.3.3 and getting the same error on "cordova build ios":

> No profiles for 'bundle_id' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a
>   provisioning profile matching 'bundle_id'.  Code signing is required
>   for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'

I've created and re-created the certificates and provisioning profiles, made sure the correct Bundle ID was selected, double clicked the certificates to install in the Keychain, downloaded the profiles, and nothing seems to be working.  I've also tried creating a build.json file in the root directory for Cordova with the following:

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "developmentTeam": "<team id>",
      "packageType": "development"
    },
    "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "developmentTeam": "<team id>",
      "packageType": "app-store"
    }
  }
```

Specifying a "provisioningProfile" with the UUID of the provisioning profile does not help either.

I'm able to complete a build successfully in Xcode and create an archive and install to my device, but it crashes right after the splash screen.  Assuming this is because Cordova didn't complete a successful build.

I've been struggling with this for weeks and have been searching forums everywhere and nothing has helped.  I've even tried closing and reopening Xcode like a lot of people have suggested and that didn't help either.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:**

I've tried restarting Xcode a bunch of times after adding provisioning profiles and have also tried removing the iOS platform using Cordova and re-adding.  Neither of these options worked.

Comment: Try to restart XCode after adding proivsioning profiles.

Comment: Tried that many times, doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the build command for iOS, the error still shows (now using Cordova version 8.1.2), but the compilation is successful now.  I'm not sure what's changed between versions, but I'm able to get a successful build for iOS now, even with the provisioning profile error.  The profiles are setup correctly in XCode and able to get a successful build in XCode as well.

**UPDATE:**

I've also noticed that the provisioning profile error doesn't show on Cordova compile when my device isn't plugged into the Mac.  But, either way, still get a successful compile, even if the error message shows on Cordova compile.

Answer (score 2):

bundle identifier in Xcode and bundle id would be same.
Check it again.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need a provision profile installed on the build machine that has the same bundle id as the bundle identifier of the application you are building.  If you are sure of this, there a few more considerations.  Please review this post:

[After upgrading to xcode 9, cordova app won't build, error 70, requires provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344443/after-upgrading-to-xcode-9-cordova-app-wont-build-error-70-requires-provisio/46370957#46370957)

It details a working set of build.json settings, and some other issues with the latest Xcode 9.