# After upgrading to xcode 9, cordova app won't build, error 70, requires provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Yesterday we upgraded from xcode 8.3.2 to version 9.  And now our enterprise distribution apache cordova ios app refuses to build.

```
2017-09-21 07:37:16.787 xcodebuild[70400:217569] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/wj/yj3cfvh954gbc_btlhcrcx7nk7t4dj/T/App Name_2017-09-21_07-37-16.786.xcdistributionlogs'.
2017-09-21 07:37:16.938 xcodebuild[70400:217569] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7ff756bbdf70>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 \"\"App Name.app\" requires a provisioning profile.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=\"App Name.app\" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the \"provisioningProfiles\" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}"
)}
error: exportArchive: "App Name.app" requires a provisioning profile.

Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""App Name.app" requires a provisioning profile." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="App Name.app" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}

** EXPORT FAILED **

Error: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,App Name.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/Shared/Workspace/github/AppName/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/Shared/Workspace/github/AppName/platforms/ios/build/device
```

(I replaced the apps name with "App Name" for this question)

I have verified that all the certs and provisioning profiles are set in xcode.  And the build.json is set.  I'm not really a Mac guy and I'm stumped on what to do next.

-Edit, Downgrading xcode to 8.3.3 fixed the problem.  Not an ideal solution but not much I can do.

Comment: I always sign manually. So far nothing gets me in trouble this way.

Comment: How is that done?

Comment: Nothing fancy. Just after add platform, before you build, open xcode and enable checkbox on 'Automatically manage signing' .  Then if there's no issue, proceed with build ios.

Comment: I could actually build in xcode no problem.  I think this is a cordova error.  Xcode didn't seem to want to give me an ipa though so i couldn't bypass cordova until they fixed it.

Comment: *-Edit, Downgrading xcode to 8.3.3 fixed the problem. Not an ideal solution but not much I can do.* This part should be posted as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: Ran into same problem, nothing changed but just upgraded to Xcode 9. hopefully Cordova will give a quick fix

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you specify your provisioning profile explicitly, like me.  Like this in your Cordova build.json:

```
"ios": {
    "debug": {
        "codeSignIdentitiy": "iPhone Developer",
        "developmentTeam":"MYTEAMID",
        "packageType": "developer",
        "iCloudContainerEnvironment": "Development"
    },
    "release": {
        "codeSignIdentitiy": "iPhone Distribution",
        "developmentTeam":"MYTEAMID",
        "provisioningProfile": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "packageType": "ad-hoc",
        "iCloudContainerEnvironment": "Production"
    }
}
```

**Please Note**
iCloudContainerEnvironment = Production/Development is only required if you use push notifications

You need to explicitly set manual signing and provide the provisioning keys in your ExportOptions.plist that is generated by Cordova.  Unfortunately Cordova is not currently generating all of the required keys.

Here is what it needs to look like, at least for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>compileBitcode</key>
  <false/>
  <key>method</key>
  <string>ad-hoc</string>
  <key>iCloudContainerEnvironment</key >
  <string>Production</string>
  <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
  <dict>
    <key>my.bundle.idenifier</key>
    <string>My Provisioning Profile Name</string>
  </dict>
  <key>signingCertificate</key>
  <string>iPhone Distribution</string>
  <key>signingStyle</key>
  <string>manual</string>
  <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
  <true/>
  <key>teamID</key>
  <string>YOURTEAMID</string>
  <key>thinning</key>
  <string>&lt;none&gt;</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The file Cordova generates @ cordova/app/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <false/>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>MYTEAMID</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

notice it is missing the important bits that Xcode 9 requires.

I generated the correct file by archiving the build manually, then exporting it which also creates the exportOptions.plist that I now use as reference.

After digging deeper, I found that this cannot be fixed after running "Cordova add platform iOS", because it is generated during the build phase dynamically.  I decided to fork the Cordova-ios repo and submit a pull request.  You may use my fork directly, or wait until the pull request is merged.

**Pull Request**
https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/338/commits

**Fork**
https://github.com/jrryhrtn/cordova-ios

**Usage notes from pull request**

See example below, please note that the provisioning profile can be the name or UUID of the profile.  Name is preferred for maintenence, as UUID changes each time to regenerate the profile.

```
{
"ios": {
    "debug": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
        "developmentTeam":"YOURTEAMID",
        "provisioningProfile": "provisioning profile name or UUID",
        "packageType": "development"
    },
    "release": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
        "developmentTeam":"YOURTEAMID",
        "provisioningProfile": "provisioning profile name or UUID",
        "packageType": "ad-hoc"
    }
}
}
```

I plan to manually patch until the/a fix is merged into the next Cordova release.  You will have to regenerate your iOS platform after the patch via "Cordova platform rm iOS" and then "Cordova platform add ~/forks/cordova-ios". ~/forks/cordova-ios my local path, use the path on your local machine where you downloaded the forked Cordova-ios repo.

**Update**

cordova-ios 4.5.2 has been officially released!  Upgrade by running the following commands: "cordova platform rm ios", and then "cordova platform add ios@4.5.2"

Cheers!

Comment: Wow what an answer.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I can confirm that this works for push notifications. Thanks!

Comment: @JerryHorton, I see that the fix has been added to cordova-ios, but a version has not been released.  Does anyone know how to require the latest version of cordova-ios directly from the repo?

Comment: @BayssMekanique "Cordova platform add ios@4.5 (not sure that is released yet) or you can add the platform from file like: Cordova platform add ~/forks/cordova-ios if you download locally

Comment: @powerc9000 Love back.  I'm glad I could help.  This was also painful for me, and I kinda thought for others to.  Felt it was time to give back a little, I use StackOverFlow all the time.  Glad I could help, peace.

Comment: @JerryHorton I have added the `cordova-ios` master branch to my project, but still have issues building with XCode 9. To my opinion I have added all that is needed to sign the app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478342/code-signing-error-code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-s

Comment: @mark-veenstra I posted an answer to the link to your question above

Comment: From where can I get "provisioning profile name or UUID" ?

Comment: You download your provisioning profiles from developer.apple.com/account.  If you have downloaded and installed the profiles, they are found @ ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/.  They are named <UUID>.mobileprovision.  If you open the file and search for UUID, you will find it and the profiles name.  Also, the name is the file name as downloaded from Apple.

Comment: @JerryHorton: I have added in config.xml same line still same issue for me

Comment: @JerryHorton : + xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath abc.xcarchive -exportPath abc.ipa -exportOptionsPlist abc/abc.plist using this line and still the same issue facing

Comment: @AndroidGeeks If you change the config.xml spec yo point to master, you then have to run "cordova rm platform iOS", then update by running "cordova platform update ios", and finally "cordova platform add ios".

Comment: @AndroidGeeks. You can also follow the instructions in the answer to download master, or my fork and use it directly.  I find it a little more straight forward.  When the fix eventually get's release in 4.5.2, you will need to do the following "cordova platform rm ios", "cordova platform update ios@4.5.2", and finally "cordova platform add ios"

Comment: @JerryHorton : I fixed this problem by adding in provisioning profile key as bundle identifier and string as provisioning profile GUID which resolved an error

Comment: @JerryHorton: I just updated to cordova-ios 4.5.2 with no success. I still get "MyApp requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature." Any idea how to fix that one?

Comment: @the-unknown You need to add "iCloudContainerEnvironment": "Development" or "iCloudContainerEnvironment": "Production" to your build.json iOS section.  At the top of this answer is an example.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't work for me.  cordova-ios 4.5.3 and it's dying on the iOS section when setup that way.  Is this change still required in ..3?

Comment: @brian-knoblauch  You will need 4.5.2 or later if you are using Xcode 9.x or later.  If you are have issues in later versions > 4.5.2 you will need to call those errors out directly.  Please post here or make another issue and post the link in a comment in this thread.  Jerry.

Comment: @JerryHorton it looks like the lines in the 2nd listing are a bit messy. Shouldn't `<key>provisioningProfiles</key>` be 2 lines lower (right before `<dict>` section with Bundle ID / Profile relations)? And then `iCloudContainerEnvironment` should be key while `Production` on the contrary should be string.

Comment: Finally got to upgrade and clean up the technical debt, we're up to 4.5.4 now, and it worked great.  Android was fubar, but iOS worked perfect.  Thank you everyone!

Comment: Thanks! The only way to get an automated build and deployment process.

Comment: `{
"ios": {
    "debug": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
        "developmentTeam":"YOURTEAMID",
        "provisioningProfile": "provisioning profile name or UUID",
        "packageType": "development"
    },
    "release": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
        "developmentTeam":"YOURTEAMID",
        "provisioningProfile": "provisioning profile name or UUID",
        "packageType": "ad-hoc"
    }
}
}`

I added your suggestion above to a **build.json** file I created in my root ionic project and it worked.

Comment: Thank god for this answer! Never found a good way to get Cordova to create ExportOptions with the Provisioning Profile added and was not able to find a good way to specify a custom ExportOptions in the Jenkins Xcode plugin. Ended up using fastlane's gym tool to specify a custom ExportOptions file and only did the export step in fastlane. And all is right in the world once again.

Comment: @JerryHorton, everytime I build with cordova build ios --device --buildConfig build.json --release , the exportOptions plist fille gets overridden and my changes as you suggested is lost. I am overriding exportoptions.plist from projectSource/Platforms/ios

Comment: I keep getting this error forever, even with `cordova-ios` 5.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

While help is coming and you don't want to use Xcode directly (and I don't judge you )... here is a temporary solution which worked fine for me:

remove ios

```
cordova platform rm ios
```

add ios from dev brunch where [this issue already fixed](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/commit/cf424b46fb37c00395c1ee9a249280efee5f65b5).
(Later you will be able to use ios v4.6.0 or whatever final # is going to be)

```
cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios.git
```

I hope it will help you too!

Answer (score 1):

For who land of the following error

```
error: exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key 'iCloudContainerEnvironment': expected one of {Development, Production}, but no value was provided
```

All you need to do it this to create a build

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release -- --iCloudContainerEnvironment=Production
```

More info:

- https://medium.com/@michele.patrassi/https-medium-com-michele-patrassi-add-icloud-icloudcontainerenvironment-to-your-ionic-ios-app-227300bf8896