# Requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

After updating Xcode to version 9.0, i started getting this error: "Requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature." when building my iOS application with Cordova. My application and configurations have not changed since my previous build.

I googled but i didn't find anything helpful.

**Solution:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370957/7199922

Tested and it works.

Comment: This has been answered in a different post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344443/after-upgrading-to-xcode-9-cordova-app-wont-build-error-70-requires-provisio/46370957#46370957

Comment: @JerryHorton i tried that already, as i mentioned this link already in one of my comments to an answer. It didn't work. :(

Comment: @JedatKinports That file is generated on every run/build so editing it manually is useless as it is rewritten each time you run `cordova build` or `cordova run`.

Comment: @n00dl3 so how can this be solved then? :/

Comment: using @JerryHorton 's cordova-ios fork or waiting for the pull request to be merged and released.

Comment: downgrading to Xcode-8 while the PR is not merged is also an alternative.

Comment: After some more research, there seems to be one more param in ExportOptions.plist I did not cover in the pull request.  iCloudContainerEnvironment = "Production" or iCloudContainerEnvironment = "Development"

Comment: I added iCloudContainerEnvironment to the build.json file, and now support mapping it to exportOptions.plist.  The fork/PR should now work for folks using push notifications.

Comment: @JerryHorton thanks for the addition for push notifications!

Answer (score 5):

**If you are using fastlane** for your builds like me, I have found that there are a number of fastlane releases that does not generate exportOptions correctly, which causes Xcode to be unable to find a provisioning profile regardless of it is installed and correctly configured.

I have found that version 2.58.0 of fastlane is working fine and have updated my `Fastfile` files to include the following line to ensure a high enough version on other machines too:

```
fastlane_version "2.58.0"
```

It will then correctly generate values like:

```
{
  "provisioningProfiles": {
    "com.name.app": "App name"
  },
  "method": "app-store",
  "teamID": "ABCDEF31593"
}
```

Comment: I'm not using fastlane. Building directly with Cordova. Did you find out what the problem was or just changed the version? Might be the same issue here.

Comment: I learnt a bit about the issue. The exportOptions are a now mandatory option to the xcodebuild command and in fastlane's case something broke the generation of provisioning profiles that goes into exportOptions. Can you verify that you have values present for provisioning in your exportOptions when doing your build?

Comment: I will try it on Monday. Don't have access to it at the moment.

Comment: I'm trying to find out if the exportOptions flag is missing in Cordova, but i don't think that it is as the file gets created.

Comment: Yes, but does the created file contain values for provisioning profiles?

Comment: I have added the contents of my exportOptions file to my question.

Comment: I also tried to add key/values like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370957/7199922 but the result was the same. do i have to add something else?

Comment: @JedatKinports I have added the values you need to be looking for in my answer.

Comment: I have this file in a xml format. And yours looks like a JSON.  So would this be ok? `<key>provisioningProfiles</key>
  <dict>
    <key>my.bundle.idenifier</key>
    <string>My Provisioning Profile Name</string>
  </dict>` I tried this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem.
`export_xcargs "-allowProvisioningUpdates"` works for me.
Please go [here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/9589) for detailed information

Comment: I' not using `fastlane`. I'm using `Cordova`.