# Check dependencies error in Cordova iOS build

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

After updating to High Sierra and Xcode 9.1, I'm unable to build Cordova apps.  The first failure was about the team being missing, so I turned that on.  I'm now hung up on:

```
Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: xxx has conflicting provisioning settings. xxx is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.1'
```

It seems pretty obvious, but when I do what it says, I don't get anywhere.  I've fiddled with all various settings of automatic and manual settings (dev and production) that seemed reasonable.  I've even built a whole new certificate and distribution profile, but no change.  I've followed instructions from [After upgrading to xcode 9, cordova app won't build, error 70, requires provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344443/after-upgrading-to-xcode-9-cordova-app-wont-build-error-70-requires-provisio/46370957?noredirect=1#comment81462808_46370957) with no luck.  I've googled up a lot of issues with the Xcode upgrade, but there doesn't seem to be a comprehensive list of exactly what needs to change for support.  I'm just finding various snippets that don't work for me...

Currently working with cordova-ios version 4.5.3.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This has eaten up most of my day...

Comment: Nope, no solution yet.  After a few days of putting in fairly hard effort on it I decided to temporarily give up on iOS and focus my efforts on our Android, Windows, and OS X versions.  Maybe a future Cordova update will magically fix iOS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a disgusting amount of time spent on this, I was finally able to get mine published... I'll outline what I remember of the workflow below:

- run `ionic cordova platform rm ios` then `ionic cordova platform add ios`
- open Xcode and select your development team, keep the signing set to automatic
- run `ionic cordova build ios --prod` – **don't add the `--release` flag**
- if you now have a .xcarchive file in platforms/ios, open it in Xcode and skip to the very bottom, otherwise continue to the next point
- open the .xcodeproj file and click `Product > Archive` – this will create the release build
- If you get the "check dependencies" error at this point:

  - uncheck / disable automatic signing
  - re-check / enable automatic signing
  - run `Product > Archive` again

This *should* successfully build your app release, at which point you'll have the option to "Submit to App Store"... Good luck!

Comment: Well, that's a rather dramatic improvement, I can actually complete a build (but not the submit) process now.  I think one of the pieces I missed was leaving off the "--release" after I'd done the rm/add of the ios platform.  Unfortunately it's failing right at the end of the app store submission, but I'd never even gotten to the Product Archive step before!

Comment: Mine was giving me an error at that point too, it should be pretty specific as to what it wants though... In my case my `resources/icon.png` needed to not have an alpha channel.

Comment: Something signing related, but I ran out of time to work on it again.  Did check to make sure my teams and signing certs were in order and they sure *look* like they are, but I've had cases before where they would suddenly mysteriously break (well before expiration) and I just had to make new ones.

Comment: Just to see if I'm getting the same results.  Did you get a Product Archive submission popup about automatically or manually signing?  I never used to see that before, but am getting it now.  None of the options I select seem to work even though it matches the certificate/team setup on the website and in XCode proper.

Comment: Try unchecking and re-checking the automatic signing option again... I believe that's what fixed it for me.

Comment: "Missing or invalid signature ... is not signed with an Apple submission certificate."  However, all the pre-upload signing stuff works fine, it's during the re-sign on upload.  If I go into developer and inspect the certificates and profiles it all looks fine.  I'm thinking I'll just do the usual create all new ones...

Comment: Yeah, if you’re sure that you’re using an App Store provision, then it wouldn’t hurt to start over at this point... I can’t think of what else could be wrong.