# cordova build ios - archive failed - No profile for team matching

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

sudo ionic cordova build ios

Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: No profile for team 'N773KY89E6' matching 'com.and56.client' found:  Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'N773KY89E6/com.and56.client'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

I am sure that I have a working Provisioning profile.
I have tried some solutions I found online, like:
[《After upgrading to xcode 9, cordova app won't build, error 70, requires provisioning profile》](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344443/after-upgrading-to-xcode-9-cordova-app-wont-build-error-70-requires-provisio/46370957#46370957)

npm:4.1.2 
cordova:8.0.0 
**cordova-ios:4.5.4
xcode:9.2**

Answer (score 1):

I was banging my head around this problem a lot, until I finally managed to solve it by 1 simple step:

**- Unplugged my iPhone from the Mac**

I was so amused and annoyed in the same time...

Hopefully this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Your build.json needs to follow the following guidelines

```
{
"ios": {
    "debug": {
    "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
    "developmentTeam":"YOURTEAMID",
    "provisioningProfile": "provisioning profile name or UUID",
    "packageType": "development"
    },
    "release": {
    "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
    "developmentTeam":"YOURTEAMID",
    "provisioningProfile": "provisioning profile name or UUID",
    "packageType": "ad-hoc"
    }
  }
}
```

> and provisioning profile needs to be created and downloaded from
>   apple.developer.com. The profile is specific to the app you are
>   building, and internally has been coded with the applications bundle
>   id. e.g com.company.MyApp. The name to use in your build.json is the
>   literal name of the profile as downloaded from apple without the
>   extension. The name is also contained inside the file is your search
>   for UUID. The UUID is also identified inside the file. When you double
>   click the file it will be installed in the
>   ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles directory, renamed to
>   .mobileprovision