# Building ios-app Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

When i try to build ios-app and deploy it in iPad connected to my PC (i use remotebuild agent on remote mac (xcode 9.2) and vs 2015 + apache cordova on my PC) i have the following error:

*Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""myapp.app" requires a provisioning profile." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription="myapp.app" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a development/distribution provisioning profile in **developer.apple.com** portal, then specify TEAMID and provisioning profile in **build.json** config file:

```
"ios": {
    "debug": {
        "codeSignIdentitiy": "iPhone Developer",
        "developmentTeam":"MYTEAMID",
        "provisioningProfile": "Provisoning profile name",
        "packageType": "developer"
    },
    "release": {
        "codeSignIdentitiy": "iPhone Distribution",
        "developmentTeam":"MYTEAMID",
        "provisioningProfile": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "packageType": "app-store"
    }
}
```

More info of how to create provisioning profile are available here, in official TACO guide : [Create a Provisioning Profile](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#create-a-provisioning-profilee)

Comment: Try to open xcode, then go in Xcode>Preferences, choose your Apple ID then click on "Download Manual Profiles" to download created provisioning. What version of xcode are you using?

Comment: If I open xCode>About Xcode i can see that i use version 9.2 of xcode. If I click "dowload manual profiles" i can see nothing. If I click on "Manage Certfificates" I can see:'Ios Development Certificates':'Untitled' - 'Creator':'my name' - 'Date Created'.'1-22-18' - 'Status':nothing.

Comment: Have you created appID="myapp.app" and relative provisioning profile on developer.apple.com portal, and installed development.cert and provisioning on mac after that? Are you building in RELEASE or DEBUG from visual studio? You have only DEVELOPMENT cert installed, then you can be able to build only in DEBUG, and you need a DEVELOPMENT provisioning profile with "myapp.app" associated.

Comment: ok maybe the error is this one tha you seid me but: 1)I created a provisioning profile and i have it. But how can i installed it on mac? if i drag that file on xcode folder i get nothing, so wich is the procedure to install it on mac?2) Yes i'm building from vs but if i try to build in debug mode i have the same error. maybe the error is that i'm not able to install the provisioning profile on mac

Comment: To install provisioning simply download it from apple portal and double click it.

Comment: i double clicked provisioning, but now how can i see if it was installed?

Comment: You can try to open xcode project under Taco-remote/builds/buildnumber on MAC or check provisioning installed on Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles folder also on mac..

Comment: I verified that in Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles there are 2 provisioning profiles and one is that one that i need (the code is right). Maybe i have to delete the other one?

Comment: Try to delete other one, but if you specify the right name of "provisioningProfile": "Provisoning profile name" in build.json it had to get the correct one. If you encounter someother build issue ry to open xcodeproj from buildnumber/platform/ios folder and chek under General/Target/Signing folder if xcode does not report more issues..

Comment: Mi sa che ci sto girando intorno con questi certificati ma non installo quello giusto. Ho creato un certificato di distribuzione  ma ottengo sempre errore anche perchè ora devo risolvere il problema di metterlo nell'ipad e verificare se è lì installato senza avere il mac. Farò una nuova domanda e flaggo questa così acquisto punti. Ancora grazie per ora.

Comment: Che io sappia devi connettere l'ipad al mac per metterci il certificato, oppure devi emettere un provisioning profile di tipo "ad-hoc" di sviluppo sul portale apple specificando l'UUID dell'ipad su cui installerai (lo vedi da itunes). (qui trovi una piccola guida su come fare https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204270188-iOS-Creating-an-Ad-Hoc-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile. Sul build.json poi specifichi come packageType: "ad-hoc". Buona fortuna.

Comment: Non ho capito se posso ma provo a continuare a farti domande in italiano da qui. Io nel mio ipad ho sicuramente installato un provisioning-profile del tipo ios-development; con questo secodo te posso creare una release sul mio ipad o non funziona perchè il tipo di provisioning è sbagliato? nel build.jason specificherei:  developmentTeam:"MYTEAMID",         codeSignIdentity:"iPhoneDeveloper",
provisioningProfile: "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
packageType:"Developer",
iCloudContainerEnvironment: "Development"

Comment: Per build development dovrebbe andare quello che hai già (il packagetype corretto è:  "packageType": "development"), mentre per release devi creare un ad-hoc. Ovviamente il development installato su ipad deve essere quello con cui buildi l'app, cioè quello per quell'APP NAME. Se lo riemetti perchè cambi qualcosa devi reinstallarlo anche su ipad. L'ad hoc invece lo crei con il codice identificativo del dispositivo su cui andrai ad installare, puoi specificarne una lista in fase emissione profilo.

Comment: Ok ma la domanda che mi pongo è: con il develpment(il provisioning che ho sull'ipad) la posso installare l'app sull'ipad? Cioè se setto 'debug' e lancio la compilazione me la installa? Oppure se setto release e compilo con build.jason settato come sopra me la installa? Posso avere una installazione con il debug o devo usare il realease e quindi mi occorre per forza un ad hoc? Scusa la mia confusione ma è questo che devo capire.

Comment: Nel tuo provisioning profile devi guardare sul portale apple se c'è l'UUID del dispositivo dove installi associato, lo vedi sulla (gestione profili del sito > provisioning profiles > development) scegli il provisioning che hai creato, fai EDIT e guardi nella tabella DEVICES se c'è il tuo. Se non c'è va aggiunto dalla scheda devices, poi fai di nuovo EDIT sul provisioning e flagghi il dispositivo, scarichi il provisioning rebuildi lo reinstalli su ipad e riesci ad installare l'ipa. Se il dispositivo invece è già associato a quel provisioning allora riesci ad installare anche subito.

Comment: Perchè se con il solo debug mi piazza comunque l'app nell'ipad intanto vedo di far funzionare quello perchè ho i certificati giusti a quanto ho capito e la mia priorità è vedere la app sull'ipad

Comment: parliamo sempre di SVILUPPO (debug), per RELEASE devi avere cert di DISTRIBUTION installato sul mac da cui buildi e provisioning distribution in modalità AD-HOC con annesso UUID del device, da quello che dici sopra hai solo certificato DEVELOPMENT installato sul mac, quindi pui al limite usare provisioning di sviluppo buildando in debug ed installare le app sui dispositivi che specifichi in quel provisioning. Il tuo errore è comunque in fase di build, l'installazione una volta compilato il .IPA puoi farla in diversi modi.

Comment: ho già guardato nel provisioning, nel file c'è  l'identificativo di 40 caratteri dell'ipad (che avevo associato nel portale degli sviluppatori) ed anche l'UUID che poi è la stringa che ho nel buid.jason alla voce provisioning profile. Quando ho creato il provioning ho associato sia il certificato di sviluppattore, l'ID app, il mio ipad...

Comment: Vedi nel build.log nella parte finale quale provisioning sta prendendo per buildare, sembrerebbe che o non l'hai sul mac o hai specificato nome sul build.json non corretto perchè non riesce a trovarlo. Prova a vedere se questa può esserti di aiuto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344443/after-upgrading-to-xcode-9-cordova-app-wont-build-error-70-requires-provisio

Comment: Sei gentilissimo frix, vado a verificare il tuo ultimo suggerimento, Ti posto l'errore che mi dà dopo avermi comunicato **ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED**.  ...Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 \"\"myapp.app\" requires a provisioning profile.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=\"myapp.app\" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the \"provisioningProfiles\" dictionary in your Export Options property list.
error : exportArchive: "tennispiu.app" requires a provisioning profile **EXPORT FAILED**... ho messo i pezzi più significativi

Comment: Verifica anche che l' ID dell'app sul config.xml corrisponda esattamente all'ID dell'app sul provisioning profile.. la fase di export è proprio quella di firma dopo la build, e sembra proprio che non trovi nessun provisioning per quell'ID, quindi o non è installato sul mac, o sono sbagliati i settings del build.json o non torna qualcosa tipo nome o tipo del provisioning.. Di più da lontano è difficile dirlo.. ;)

Comment: Aspetta... nel provisioning ho <key>AppIDName</key><string>tennispiu</string>... mentre in nome config.xml ho come nome pacchetto (id) com.mionome.tennispiu... prima ho cambiato questo ma mi ha dato dicendomi che il nome giusto era com.mionome.tennispiu... dici che ho sbagliato a mettere l'id giusto nel provisioning? Ossia tennispiu invece di com.mionome.tennispiu?

Comment: errata corrige:in nome pacchetto, non in nome, ho com.mionome.tennispiu e come l'ho cambiato me lo ha segnalato...

Comment: Come APPID dell'app associata al provisioning, e come ID del config.xml <widget id> dovresti avere com.mionome.tennispiu. L'appID lo verifichi sempre sul portale apple su Identifiers>AppIDs, o editando il provisioning emesso.

Comment: il mio appid (da portale) è così settato: name>tennispiu; prefix: XXXXXXX;id>com.mionome.id; effettivamente nel provisioning "<key>AppIDName</key><string>tennispiu</string>" corrisponde (il name intendo)...e nel config.xml ho  <widget id=com.mionome.tennispiu> che dovrebbe essere giusto, infatti se quest'ultimo lo cambio(per esempio con solo tennispiu) mi dà errore dicendomi che il provisioning è associato ad id com.mionome.tenispiu che non corriponde a tennispiu... sembra quindi corretto l'idapp

Comment: Ok, sembra quindi sbagliato il build.json se nella solution xcode ti dice che hai provisioning e nome corretti. Prova a passare esattamente il nome del provisioning che vedi visualizzato sul portale apple come "provisioningProfile" su build.json nella sezione "debug" ed il "teamid" che vedi tra parentesi nel tuo .cert di sviluppo o sempre sul portale apple in alto, oppure ancora all'interno del provisioning come ApplicationIdentifierPrefix.

Comment: stesso errore, a questo punto devo verificare che il provisioning che ho installato nell'ipad sia quello giusto, domani mi faccio prestare un mac e vedo di verificarlo. Per il momento un grazie grandissimo, posterò qua le verifiche del caso :-)

Comment: ho fatto tutte le verifiche del caso, credo sia un problema di xcode 9 e sinceramente di fronte a questo mi sto arrendendo :(

Comment: l'ultima cosa che vorrei domandarti è se mi confermi che setto la compilazione su debug-ios-dispositivo locale e se non ci fossero errori allora l'applicazione sarebbe installata sul dispositivo, oppure per vedere l'applicazione sul dispositivo devo fare release-ios-dispositivo locale con annesso un tipo di certificato adhoc? Con certificato development debug-ios-dispositivo locale posso comunque installare l'applicazione nel mio device? E' di questo che voglio essere sicuro

Comment: Il tuo problema ripeto è però di compilazione per problemi di provisioning/certificati in fase di firma del pacchetto compilato. Volendo puoi aprire la solution di xcode sul mac e provare a compilarla da lì per generare l'IPA, poi trasferirla su un pc locale ed installartela via link di DIAWI. L'installazione però è successiva al problema che hai tu.

Comment: quale versione di platform-ios usi? Ora provo ad impostare il tutto con le tue stesse versioni. Ho xcode 9.2, cordova 8.0 ma lo porto a 7.1, platform ios 4.3.1

Comment: cordova-ios@4.3.1, ma il tuo a mio avviso è un problema di firma su provisioning/certificati. L'app viene buildata correttamente, ma non firmata.. Se hai un mac non remoto disponibile prova su quello in modo da poter mettere mano al keystore ed aprire eventualmente il progetto di XCODE nativo, provando poi a firmare il pacchetto direttamente da lì..

Comment: Sono arrivato a caricare xarchive nello store, non mi dà problemi con i certificati ma mi dà errore perchè chiede l'imm.png 1024x1024. Ho messo quella immagine sia nella cartella icons che in AppIcon.appiconset ma l'errore persiste... ti è mai capitato qualcosa di simile?